# Input box has no space in between on mobile view but looks okay on laptop

Tags: html, css

Input box has no space in between on mobile view but looks okay on laptop. Ive tried to put br tag to make space in between the input boxes but the laptop view will change its look.

```
                                <div class="panel panel-flat " style=" border: 0; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.18); border-radius: 9px;">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group-xlg">
                                                <input placeholder="ስም" id="name" maxlength="12" name="ስም" type="text" style="border-radius: 9px; border: 0; background-color: #F3F4F6"
                                                       class="form-control border-bottom-0 text-size-large input-xlg">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group-xlg">
                                                <input placeholder="የአባት ስም" id="fname" style="border-radius: 9px; border: 0; background-color: #F3F4F6" maxlength="12" name="የአባት ስም" type="text"
                                                       class="form-control border-teal border-lg input-xlg">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

[image: Here is the image]

[image]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: i have tried to include a picture which makes the question more clear. but it is not showing up

Comment: Add the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it.

```
                                <div class="panel panel-flat " style=" border: 0; box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.18); border-radius: 9px;">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;">
                                            <div class="form-group-xlg">
                                                <input placeholder="ስም" id="name" maxlength="12" name="ስም" type="text" style="border-radius: 9px; border: 0; background-color: #F3F4F6"
                                                       class="form-control border-bottom-0 text-size-large input-xlg ">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: 7px;padding-bottom: 7px;">
                                            <div class="form-group-xlg">
                                                <input placeholder="የአባት ስም" id="fname" style="border-radius: 9px; border: 0; background-color: #F3F4F6" maxlength="12" name="የአባት ስም" type="text"
                                                       class="form-control border-teal border-lg input-xlg">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="padding-top: 7px;">
                                            <div class="form-group-xlg text-center ">
                                                <input placeholder="እድሜ" id="age" style="border-radius: 9px; border: 0; background-color: #F3F4F6"
                                                       maxlength="2" name="እድሜ" type="tel"
                                                       class="form-control border-lg input-xlg text-center">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use `form-group` elements and not `form-group-xxl`. Please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qtL1forw/1/ .

If you must use `form-group-xxl`, you can add top and bottom padding to the element.

The next learning step would be to stay away from inline styling and place your style rules in a stylesheet. Best of luck!

Comment: You won't achieve what you want using inline styles. If you want to apply different styles based on the viewport, then you'll need to place your styles rules in a stylesheet (or within `<style></style` tags) and utilize media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries